AM radio transmitter with max. 1m range - what schematic should I search/build?
For one of my project, I would need some low-power consumption AM transmitter module.
I'm very sure that I need amplitude-modulation broadcasting between the consumer AM radio bands (in Hungary : 530-1600kHz), detectable by any inexpensive pocket radio with a fully opened antenna. Nor the conventional 433MHz transceiver modules, nor any FM-transmitter is preferable by me, I would like to AM.
The desired range would be around 0.5-1m, no more than that. Even a bigger range would be not beneficial for me, I would like to at least heavy attenuations/signal-loss over 1 meter.
For sound quality, anything a little_bin better than what is minimally sufficient for morse coding is great; mono telephone quality would be absolutely exquisite for the desired signal.
What are my preferences are the following:

be as low-power consumption, as it is achievable with a homemade tool; if that could be targeted, a 1 week continuous broadcasting from a ~3000mAH 18650 cell would be ok;
on-the-fly tuning is not needed, but it would be great, if I could calculate/redesign the base for an officially less used AM band;
that would be also great, if I could somehow easily set the range with a pocket radio;

I need to build about a dozen modules, so a less complicated, but still ideal schematic would be preferred.
Edit : Well, someone - on an other forum - wrote me that with these requirements I can solve it only with a SN74LS00 Quad NAND gate IC and a capacitor : https://i.ibb.co/rHzcTR4/buta-AM.jpg
("Bemenet" is the audio input)
But I don't understand how the heck can it transmit? But it should, cause it was built by him, even more than onec (about ~40 years ago).

There are many low-power broadcast band transmitters schematics on the web, e.g., https://search.brave.com/search?q=low-power+broadcast+band+transmitters+schematic . What research have you done?

It might be illegal to manufacture, posess, and use a radio transmitter you have no permit for. No matter how short range or low power.

@DrMoishePippik which impressed me first is this ?solution? almost only with an 555 IC : https://www.electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/low-range-radio-transmitter
But there is no detailed info about it's operation and about what sets the 600kHz carrier.
The second one is this : https://obrazki.elektroda.pl/1832379200_1365688278.jpg which I found, and seems to be a bit legit with it's block separation noted on the drawing.

You mention Morse coding as an application, and also mono telephone audio as an application. If you expect a standard AM radio receiver to receive Morse code as a tone (for example, "beep...beep...beep" for Morse letter S) then an additional audio 700 Hertz oscillator would be required to provide AM modulation to the transmitter carrier. So Morse versus voice_audio require different transmitter circuits.

@Justme I wonder how anyone ever designs & tests radios with this logic?

@Aaron What kind of radios you are talking about? The devices built and manufactured are required to follow local laws about transmitter frequencies, bandwidths, power output and duty cycle. Anything not permitted is illegal. Of course HAMs (radio amateurs) are permitted to build, possess and operate transmitters with more relaxed permissions than standard consumers, but they are expected to know what is legal and illegal for them too. You can't build a random radio transmitter circuit from the Internet without some understanding as it could disturb signal reception of your neighbours.

@Justme There are also licenses available in most jurisdictions for low-power testing in an R&D setting.

@glen_geek OK, I see, mentioning morse coding was not a good idea.
My application would be voice_audio transmitting within a 1m range (with max. at a telephone quality)

This circuit via the search.brave link would suit. Not very complex or costly. Easily tuned. Even simpler is possible. https://www.circuitstoday.com/am-transmitter-circuit

@Justme, it depends on the locale. U.S.A.,, for example, Part 15 of the FCC rules allows unlicensed transmission where range is <200 feet (~66 m): https://www.fcc.gov/media/radio/low-power-radio-general-information . In Russia, the operator might disappear.

@Justme when I was young I built a AM band transmitter and was assured by the magazine I got the circuit from that it was legal because it was under some minimum power, perhaps 100 mW. I don't recall exactly. It transmitted about 10 feet.

@Justme Maybe you had a specific vision in mind when you made that statement, but as someone who has developed RF devices, I can assure you that the process is, build device, test device, take device to certification lab.  Not get certification first for something you intend to build. They'll look at you like you're crazy.

At 1.6 MHz max, I'd probably just do direct digital synthesis from a fast modern microcontroller. An STM32 with an external buffer on the DAC pin can do up to 5 MS/s (see AN4566) so you wouldn't even need an external high-speed DAC.
Use a lookup table based NCO to generate your carrier, then multiply by a copy of your baseband signal + a DC offset to avoid overmodulation. Pipe to the DAC via DMA.
On the analog side, cascade a few Sallen-Key filters together as a reconstruction filter. Have the last stage be a fully differential amplifier that drives a loop antenna.

Sounds like fun but almost certainly overly complex for his requirement.
